# Jersey web service returns 204 no content

Tags: java, spring, jersey, aop, spring-aop

## Environment:

- Spring 4.2.2
- Jersey 1.19

## Description:

### AOP Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
       ">
    <!-- Aop Bean -->
    <bean id="wsChecker" class="xn.safephone.webapp.aop.AopWebServiceChecker"/>
    <!-- Aop Configuration -->
    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="aopWsChecker" ref="wsChecker">
            <aop:pointcut id="aopWs" expression="execution (* xn.safephone.webapp.webservices.*.*(..))"/>
            <aop:around method="doAround" pointcut-ref="aopWs"/>
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

### web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST-Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>xn.safephone.webapp.webservices</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST-Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### Jersey Web Service Class

```
@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String test() {
    return "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
}
```

### AOP Class

```
public class AopWebServiceChecker {
    public void doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("1");
        joinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("2");
    }
}
```

## Result:

if I run the web service with AOP, there is no error, but the client returns "204 No Content". if I disable AOP, everything is well. so that why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that with an around-advice, you are expected to return a value; the value being the return value from the actual advised method invocation. The reason is that an around-advice allows you to modify the return value if need be.

Currently you are returning void, which has the affect of the resource method invocation returning null. The default behavior for Jersey when returning nul is to just send a 204 No Content with no data, because there is no data.

The result of invoking `joinPoint.proceed()` on a method return a value, will be the return value of that method invocation. So just get a reference to the value and return it.

```
public Object doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("1");
    Object retValue = joinPoint.proceed();
    System.out.println("2");
    return retValue;
}
```

**See Also:**

- [Around Advice (from Spring docs)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-ataspectj-around-advice)